# CURL, wget and file_get_contents

Tags: php, curl, wget, file-get-contents

I have encountered a problem using the PHP command `file_get_contents()` and both `wget` and `curl` with Terminal on MacOS.

The problem is that with some websites I only get a `HTML` file or a text of weird symbols. I am guessing it has to do something with encoding but I haven't found anything.

Why is this occurring and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Detect what kind of encoding is it. Try the below line.

```
echo mb_detect_encoding($str); //$str is what you get after using file_get_contents
```

It is not OS dependent, rather content specific.

Comment: Agree, the encoding is content dependent.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good idea to include this fields in your request header:

```
Accept  */*
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
```